# window Scheduler of C# Console Application calling WCF fails

Tags: c#, wcf, console

I have a C# Console application that get data from remote WCF service.   the app runs fine in Visual studio as well as if I simply double click on the application.exe files in the C# Release Bin folder.   Both cases runs fine.

However, When I try to schedule the run via Windows scheduler I get this error

> The remote name could not be resolved:    at
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(TransportContext& context) 
>   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpOutput.WebRequestHttpOutput.GetOutputStream()

Any idea why double clicking the console application.exe works fine, but not running it using windows scheduler. The error says it can't resolve the service address when I run via Windows Scheduler.

Full stack trace:

> System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException: There was no endpoint
>   listening at https://abc.defg.com:444/somedata.svc that could accept
>   the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP
>   action. See InnerException, if present, for more details. --->
>   System.Net.WebException: The remote name could not be resolved:
>   'abc.defg.com'    at
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(TransportContext& context) 
>   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpOutput.WebRequestHttpOutput.GetOutputStream()
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>
> Server stack trace:     at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpOutput.WebRequestHttpOutput.GetOutputStream()
>   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpOutput.Send(TimeSpan timeout)
>   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.SendRequest(Message
>   message, TimeSpan timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message,
>   TimeSpan timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message
>   message, TimeSpan timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action,
>   Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins,
>   Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage
>   methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage
>   message)

Comment: Did you try going to the url? Does it result in an error or do you actually see something? Is the task in windows scheduler running as a different user?

Comment: Hi ... I can go to the url from a web browser with no problem and I actually downloaded the client class class to use in my console app.  The task in windows scheduler runs under my own login credentials.

Comment: Is your service hosted in IIS?

Comment: Hi Tom ... Thank you for the follow up.   It is a third party remote service with login credentials provided.  I am not sure if hosted on IIS but the ask via email.  I am wondering how does this affect the task scheduler?

Comment: Hi ... it was an intranet firewall issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an intranet firewall issue.